# How can I merge this two recursive functions into one?

Tags: php, recursion

I want to merge this two functions into one because I want a more readable code, but I can't finding a solution.
Can you help me, please?

```
function setTplArray_fn($data) {
   $array = [];
   if (!is_array($data)) {
       return htmlspecialchars($data);
   }
   else {
       foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
           $array[htmlspecialchars($key)] = setTplArray_fn($value);
       }
   }

   return $array;
}

function setTplArray($key, $data) {
   global $tplArray;

   $tplArray[$key] = setTplArray_fn($data);
}
```

Comment: What is you data looking like?

Comment: An array or multi dimensional array with a int/string key and a value that can be both another array or a string value, if it is an array the function iterate throughout itself and "sanitize" with htmlspecialchars all values.

Answer (score 3):

Pulling a block of code out that does a single thing into a dedicated function is a very common best practice in programming. Further, recursion without a dedicated function really makes code *harder* to read, at least in my (and everyone I ever met) opinion.

If you want to make your code more readable, add some comments and type hints, reorganize the code a bit, and name things in a clear manner.

For instance, although I don't know much about your codebase, I'd rewrite your function like this:

```php
/**
 * @param array|string $data
 * @return array|string
 */
function sanitizeTplValues($data) {
    // If passed a string, just sanitize it normally
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        return htmlspecialchars($data);
    }

    // If passed an array, sanitize both the key and the values
    // NOTE: The value sanitization recursively calls this same function
    $array = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $array[htmlspecialchars($key)] = sanitizeTplValues($value);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

- At the top, I added [DocBlock](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/guides/docblocks.html) tags which pretty much every modern IDE supports. A description would be a good idea here, too, but I'll leave that for you.
- I renamed the function to better align with what (I think) it does
- Often, `else` isn't actually needed which is the case here. We can just `return` early and our brains can assume that once we get passed the first `if`, we are guaranteed to have an array
- I moved the array declaration below the first block, since it isn't used there
- I added comments, although it could be argued that the code is "obvious enough"
- I explicitly called out the recursion in the code. I personally prefer to do this with `NOTE:` syntax, although some people think that a note in a comment is weird.

The calling code only changed slightly, with some of the above applied to it:

```php
/**
 * @param string $key
 * @param array|string $data
 */
function setTplArray(string $key, $data) {
    global $tplArray;

    $tplArray[$key] = sanitizeTplValues($data);
}
```

All of the changes that I made are based on a combination of industry standard recommendations as well as my own personal preferences. They aren't absolute in any way, and you can pick and choose what works for you.

I have written a lot of recursive code, and one of the things that you have to decide early on is "should this be one function or two", and 99% of the time I recommend two functions. If you just have one, your code has to figure out how to bootstrap itself. This is often done with optional null parameters, depth checks, or magic values, all of which is just asking for trouble. If you can instead have one function that does the bootstrapping logic for you, and the other function is always 100% recursive, it is a clear separation of concerns and much easier to maintain.